# Laravel Mix: How can I concat PostCss task with a separate sass task?

Tags: sass, laravel-mix, postcss

My first task takes my SCSS entry file.

```js
// Compile SCSS
mix.sass('src/scss/main.scss', 'dist/css/sass-compiled.css');
```

My second takes my PostCss file for TailwindCSS.

```js
// Compile PostCSS
mix.postCss("src/css/site.pcss", "dist/css/tailwind.css", [
  require('tailwindcss/nesting'),
  require('tailwindcss')
])
```

I want to concat the output into a single frontend-styles.css file.

I tried running both files through mix.sass() with .options({ PostCSS }) but couldn't get that to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have the first part right. Next, create a new task that combines the output files. You can use the `mix.combine()` method to merge multiple files into one:

```
mix.combine([
  'dist/css/sass-compiled.css',
  'dist/css/tailwind.css'
], 'dist/css/frontend-styles.css');
```

Then just run: `npm run dev`